# Using preg_match() in PHP to validate complete string match not just found

Tags: php, regex

How do I get php preg_match to return false if a string contains characters other than the regex specified?

This is what I currently have, but it returns true even if illegal characters are included in the $data

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .:_]+$/i', $data)) {
}
```

Please see example below.
http://rubular.com/r/Fimhi0Rgc5

Thanks!

Comment: So where does it match illegal characters?

Comment: Define: illegal characters

Answer (score 1):

[Citing from the docs](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

So preg_match NEVER returns true. It returns 1, which acts as true, or 0 which acts as false if the pattern was not found. And I cannot see which illegal characters you do have that get accepted, (please provide an example) - I do assume the pattern is correct.

Comment: Technically yes, but we can interpret 1 as meaning true, or even the asker's reference to 'true' as 1.

Comment: Because "false" is returned on an error, I'd rather handle the real return values. Not correctly `===` checking return values leads to certain nasty bugs.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you're saying. In the event of an error, False would be interpreted as True since it is a non-zero value.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are suggesting: if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .:_]+$/i', $data)==1) ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are saying to see if it can find any of those characters in your string.  What you probably want to do is use the caret `^` operator inside of your braces and then if it finds a match there, you've got illegal characters.

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 .:_]/i', $data)) {
    // ILLEGAL CHARACTERS DETECTED
}
else {
    // NO ILLEGAL CHARACTERS DETECTED
}
```

Comment: Well, turning around the logic is not that easy with regular expressions. I do prefer to search the whole string for something I do mention, with anchors left and right.

Comment: Technically this does the same exact thing except it returns the opposite of what his returns.

Comment: right, unfortunately I need something that does the exact opposite. Illegal characters are those not covered under '/[^a-z0-9 .:_]/i'

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you never close the if statement.

You can change this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .:_]+$/i', $data) {
}
```

To this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .:_]+$/i', $data)) {
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion (I was in a hurry)
please assume correct syntax.

Comment: In that case, there is nothing wrong with the code.  However, saying assuming correct syntax leaves a wide margin of possible error.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The issue i'm concerned with is how to detect illegal characters with preg_match given set of legal characters such as a-z0-9 .:_ ?

Comment: It should be doing that.  What particular input is not working?  What is something that you set as the `$data` variable and did not give the desired results?